# How to enumerate items in a dictionary with enumerate( ) in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension, enumerate

As the title suggests I wanted to enumerate the key and its values (without brackets) in python.
I tried the following code :

```py
example_dict = {'left':'<','right':'>','up':'^','down':'v',}
[print(i,j,a) for (i,j,a) in enumerate(example_dict.items())]
```

But it doesn't work.
I want the output to be like this

```
0 left <
1 right >
2 up ^
3 down v
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: try: `[print(i,j,a) for i, (j,a) in enumerate(example_dict.items())]`. Also, the parentheses around "example_dict" are useless.

Comment: Try tu run `[print(all) for all in enumerate(a.items())]` so really see what you're unpacking. @wjandrea already provided a good answer :-)

Comment: That is handy. Ok I will delete my former comment then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case enumerate returns `(index, (key, value))`, so you just need to change your unpacking to `for i, (j, a)`, though personally I would use `k, v` instead of `j, a` in an example.

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(example_dict.items()):
    print(i, k, v)
```

BTW, [don't use a comprehension for side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/4518341); just use a for-loop.

Comment: Oh did you mean I should use comprehension only for like print stuff from a list and not use a for loop for printing out stuff from a list with modifiers like enumerate etc.?

Comment: @Humble_Snowman I mean, list comprehensions are meant for building lists, but your end goal is actually to print, not build a list. The list that gets built is `[None, None, None, None]`, which is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

As in Alexandre's comment, the code would work like this:

```
for (i, (name, sym)) in enumerate(example_dict.items()):
    print(i, name, sym)
```

A comment about style: while comprehension is really neat when computing values, using it for a loop of printing would work, but would obfuscate the intent of your code, making it less readable.

Comment: I didn't understand "using it for a loop of printing". Can you explain it in simpler terms?

Comment: You used a comprehension expression for printing:

    [print(i,j,a) for (i,j,a) in enumerate(example_dict.items())]

There are two problems with this: 1) you a computing a list (possibly a big one) of None values (which are returned by print); 2) You hide what should be, and, in my code, evidently is, an output operation, inside an expression of a computation.