# unpack enumerated zip in python

Tags: python

I have three lists that I want to iterate on with an index. For that, I tried to use `enumerate(zip(x, y, z))`, but when I try to unpack that, it fails

```
[f.write('mVtet0.row({}) = Eigen::Vector3d({}, {}, {})\n'.format(i, x,y,z) for i, x, y, z in enumerate(zip(x,y,z))]
```

Gives the following error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`

I understand the issue, enumerate creates a tuple with the index and the result of the zip. What is the correct way to unpack everything?

Comment: Related: [How to enumerate items in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61595308/4518341)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you get `int` and a `tuple`. Enclose x, y, z in brackets to make it `tuple`.

```
[f.write('mVtet0.row({}) = Eigen::Vector3d({}, {}, {})\n'.format(i, x,y,z) 
 for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(x,y,z))]
```

That said, in my opinion this is [abuse of list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects) with sole purpose to make it one-liner. Better use regular loop - it will be way more readable. And also better use f-strings.

```
for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(x,y,z)):
    f.write(f'mVtet0.row({i}) = Eigen::Vector3d({x}, {y}, {z})\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Thanks for the tip about the f-string. I didn't know it was possible to use them this way